# Rails 3.2 : "uninitialized constant" when assigning a value to a nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

A user has many roles. In routes.rb, it is:

```
resources :users do
  resources :user_roles
end
```

In model user, it is:

```
has_many :user_roles, :dependent => :destroy    
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_roles, :allow_destroy => true
validates_presence_of :user_roles
```

In model user_role, it is:

```
belongs_to :user 
belongs_to :role_definition, :class_name => 'RoleDefinition'
```

In controller new, it has:

```
@user.user_roles.build
```

In controller create, there is line:

```
@user.user_roles << RoleDefinition.where(name: 'customer').first.id
```

However it return error in execution:

```
@user.user_roles << 2 uninitialized constant UserRole
```

@user.user_roles returns `Empty Array` in debug before the << assignment:

```
@user.user_roles=Empty Array
```

What we have missed with the code above?

Comment: What is RoleDefination?

Comment: Please add your models code in question.

Comment: Have you got a typo in your routes (should be `resources :user_roles`)?

Comment: Model code added for both user and user_role model!

Comment: RoleDefinition is a table holding the definition of the role. For example, a user could be a sales (role) or engineer (role). A user may have more than one role.

Comment: @RichPeck, it is a typo in the post. Just added colon.

Comment: The error disappears after fields_for is added to view for user role. It seems that the nested field can only be filled in by fields_for on the view and can not be assigned in controller (or we don't know how to assign it in controller. not sure if this is a right statement in other cases).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've got a problem with the declaration or association of the `UserRole` model:

```
#app/models/user_role.rb
class UserRole < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_roles, class_name: "UserRole"
end
```

Comment: Just updated code for both model user and user_role. The definition is in the model.

Comment: Added class_name: 'UserRole' in has_many :user_roles and the error is the same.

Comment: The error disappears after fields_for is added to view for user role. It seems that the nested field can only be filled in by fields_for on the view and can not be assigned in controller (or we don't know how to assign it in controller. not sure if this is a right statement in other cases).